# Using fork() and execlp to count lines

Tags: c, exec, fork, line, line-count

I'm trying to read a file, count the lines of that file, and then present the result in the end. I got everything working out great the only problem is the execlp command, I have no idea how to work with.

The code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#define exit_on_error(s,m) if (s < 0) { perror(m); exit(1); } 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i, status, total=0, F, n=0;

    for(i=1; i<argc; i++){
        if(fork()==0){
            F=open(argv[i], O_RDONLY);
            exit_on_error(F,"Erro na abertura do ficheiro");
            if(fork()==0)
            {
                wait();

                // ?????????????                                  

                execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL);
            }
            close (F);
            return (0);
        }
        else{
            wait(&status);
            total += status >> 8;
        }
    }


    for(i=1; i<argc; i++){
        printf("PID=(%d), Ficheiro %s\n", getpid(), argv[i]);
    }
    for(i=1; i<argc; i++){
        printf("Numero de linhas do ficheiro %s: [%d]\n", argv[i], n);
    }
    printf("Ficheiros: [%d]---Erros: [%d]\n", --argc, total);

}
```

---

And it shows something like this:
name of the program is 2.c

./2 phonecontacts.txt ddd

Erro na abertura do ficheiro: No such file or directory

PID=(3565), Ficheiro phonecontact.txt (File containing 20 lines)

PID=(3565), Ficheiro ddd (this one doesn't exist)

Numero de linhas do ficheiro phonecontact.txt: [0] (it was supposed to show 20 lines here)

Numero de linhas do ficheiro ddd: [0] (this one doesn't exist)

Ficheiros: [2]---Erros[1]

wc: standard input: Input/output error 0

Answer (score 0):

After messing with it a little bit I managed to solve my problem:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        int i, status, total=0, F;

        for(i=1; i<argc; i++){
                if(fork()==0){
                        close(0);
                        F=open(argv[i], O_RDONLY);
                        exit_on_error(F,"Erro na abertura do ficheiro");
                        if(fork())
                        {
                                printf("Numero de linhas do ficheiro %s: \n", arg$
                                execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL);
                        }
                        close (F);
                        return (0);
                }
                else{
                        wait(&status);
                        total += status >> 8;
                }
                printf("PID=(%d), Ficheiro %s\n", getpid(), argv[i]);
        }
        printf("Ficheiros: [%d]---Erros: [%d]\n", --argc, total);
}
```

This is the code fully functional.